# BTRFS. Unallocated space

Tags: linux, ubuntu, файловая-система

столкнулся с проблемой нехватки места на диске. Через `df -h` 100% загрузки диска не было, всего 29%. Нашел что у меня каким то образом было не распределено 140ГБ места.

```
$ sudo btrfs filesystem usage -T /
Overall:
    Device size:         195.57GiB
    Device allocated:         49.06GiB
    Device unallocated:      146.51GiB
    Device missing:          0.00B
    Used:             46.37GiB
    Free (estimated):        148.21GiB  (min: 74.96GiB)
    Data ratio:               1.00
    Metadata ratio:           2.00
    Global reserve:      192.00MiB  (used: 0.00B)

                                      Data     Metadata  System              
Id Path                               single   DUP       DUP      Unallocated
-- ---------------------------------- -------- --------- -------- -----------
 1 /dev/mapper/USER--ROOT-ROOT--LV 47.00GiB   2.00GiB 64.00MiB   146.51GiB
-- ---------------------------------- -------- --------- -------- -----------
   Total                              47.00GiB   1.00GiB 32.00MiB   146.51GiB
   Used                               45.30GiB 549.25MiB 16.00KiB
```

Подскажите, как можно добавить не распределенную часть диска

Пробовал след.команды:

```
$ btrfs fs resize max /
$ btrfs balance start
```

Не помогает

Comment: «столкнулся с проблемой нехватки места на диске» — как именно столкнулись? Почему вы решили, что к этому может иметь отношение именно btrfs, а не например tmpfs или /boot какой-нибудь?

Comment: Потому что tmpfs практически пустые

Comment: При попытке создать папку "mkdir tt" выходила ошибка "No space left on device"

Comment: df -h. Показал что свободно 100+ Гб памяти, inodes на btrfs не показываются. Почистил немного логов, после получилось создать папку

Comment: /dev/mapper/USER--ROOT-ROOT--LV  196G   47G  149G  24% /